# error when installing mod_wsgi for python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have installed mod_wsgi from source to use python2.7 like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi.git
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7
make
make install
```

When I try to start apache, I get the error:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 1020 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/django/shared/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/django/shared/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/django/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/django

<Directory /var/www/html/django>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Why is apache not finding mod_wsgi?

Comment: Have you actually told Apache to load the module?

Comment: @abarnert do you know how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @abarnert mentioned above, I didn't not add the line to the modules section of apache config.  Adding that solved the problem.  This apparently doesn't get added automatically when you add mod_wsgi from source as opposed to a yum install.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your entire config file, you never told Apache to load the module.

That's why the error message says "Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled **or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**".

See [`LoadModule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) for reference, [DSO support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/dso.html) for an introduction, and the sample configs that come with Apache for examples.

Comment: do you what the mod_wsgi module is called so that i might load it in apache?

Comment: @Atma: It's [in the docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Loading_Module_Into_Apache).